# Every $p$-elementary abelian group is characteristically simple

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, automorphism-group

Based on the following [proof](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Automorphism_group_is_transitive_on_non-identity_elements_implies_characteristically_simple) my attempt is to prove that:

> If $G$ is $p$-elementary abelian then ${\rm Aut}(G)$ acts transitively on $G\setminus\{1\}$.

I'm stuck on this. But I tried a few things, for example, I know that every $p$-elementary abelian group has a $\mathbb{Z}_p$-vector space structure and $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p^n$ for some $n$. So viewing $G$ as a vector space we have that the automorphisms of $G$ are precisely the linear transformations $T:G\to G$ with $\ker(T) = 0$. Then
$$
{\rm Aut}(G) = \{T:G\to G \mid ker(T) = 0\} \simeq GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p).
$$
So I need to prove that the general linear group $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{Z}_p^n \setminus \{0\}$. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exactly right: this is equivalent to showing that $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{Z}_p^n \setminus \{0\}$. There's nothing special about $\mathbb{Z}_p$ here, actually, this is true over any field!

**Claim** Let $k$ be a field and let $n$ be a natural number. Then $\mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ acts transitively on $k^n \setminus \{0\}$.

To prove this, you need to take arbitrary elements $v, w \in k^n \setminus \{0\}$ and then construct an element $T \in \mathrm{GL}_n(k)$ such that $T(v) = w$. Remember: a linear transformation is uniquely determined by its action on a basis. Moreover, a linear transformation is invertible iff it sends bases to bases.

So, you want to pick bases $\beta$ and $\beta'$ for $k^n$, and then define $T$ by mapping $\beta$ (bijectively) to $\beta'$. If you make convenient choices for $\beta$ and $\beta'$, it will be easy to ensure that $v$ is sent to $w$!

Comment: I just need to extend the vectors $v,w$ to bases $\beta = \{v_1=v,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ and $\beta' = \{w_1=w,w_2,\ldots,w_n\}$, respectively. Then define $T$ such that $Tv_i = w_i$.

Comment: Exactly right :)